# Disabling some controls after the submit button is successful

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

After user fills some values in the form and clicks the submit button I want to disable some controls on the form for example some text boxes and some drop down controls.

Currently my drop down starts like this:

```
<select name="myquestion_@i" id="questionselect" >
```

How can I modify it to get disabled after Submit button is clicked? I don't want JS. Just directly with MVC.

I am new to MVC but I think I should do something like this maybe?

```
<select name="myquestion_@i" id="questionselect" disabled = @Model.DissableIt>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="myquestion_@i" id="questionselect"
@{
    if(Model.DissableIt)
    {
        @:disabled="disabled"
    }
}
>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Worked.